# Stargazer HTML Output, no frame and lines

Tags: html, r, stargazer

I work with R-Studio (Version 0.98.1102) and use the stargazer package (5.1). It all works properly, but when I use the type="html" function, my output looks quite ugly, there is no frame, no lines, it's just a white document with numbers and text. Even when i change the style="" function to different inputs, it always looks the same.

Has anyone an idea? I'm working with a MacBook Pro, but I don't think that this should be a problem....
Thank you very much for your help!

---

@bgoldst thank you!

but when I type the same thing:

stargazer(attitude,
          type="html",
          out="test.html")

i also get that code, but my HTML-Output is different from yours. I don't habe this three black lines in the table, and the font looks a bit different.

So it definitely must be a problem with my computer...I cannot understand that :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on OSX and I had the same problem visualizing the HTML output in Safari. I solved the problem by adding the option

```
out.header = TRUE
```

to stargazer. For example:

```
stargazer(attitude, type="html", out="test.html", out.header=TRUE)
```

creates the file test.html. When I open it in Safari it looks like this:

[image]

When out.header=TRUE, stargazer adds a HTML header to the output file. Otherwise it only saves the chunk that creates the table.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the stargazer package, and it seems pretty limited to me. I tried running:

```
stargazer(attitude,type='html');
##
## <table style="text-align:center"><tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Statistic</td><td>N</td><td>Mean</td><td>St. Dev.</td><td>Min</td><td>Max</td></tr>
## <tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">rating</td><td>30</td><td>64.633</td><td>12.173</td><td>40</td><td>85</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">complaints</td><td>30</td><td>66.600</td><td>13.315</td><td>37</td><td>90</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">privileges</td><td>30</td><td>53.133</td><td>12.235</td><td>30</td><td>83</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">learning</td><td>30</td><td>56.367</td><td>11.737</td><td>34</td><td>75</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">raises</td><td>30</td><td>64.633</td><td>10.397</td><td>43</td><td>88</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">critical</td><td>30</td><td>74.767</td><td>9.895</td><td>49</td><td>92</td></tr>
## <tr><td style="text-align:left">advance</td><td>30</td><td>42.933</td><td>10.289</td><td>25</td><td>72</td></tr>
## <tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr></table>
```

This shows up like this on a web page:

[image: attitude-table]

There don't seem to be many graphical customization options to the [`stargazer()`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf#page=2) command. I tried all the supported [styles](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf#page=21), and the only ones that had any effect were `'commadefault'`, which changed the decimals to commas in the numbers, `'io'`, which capitalized the statistic names for some reason, and `'jpam'`, which slightly modified the column names (e.g. `Max` became `Maximum` and `St. Dev.` became `SD`).

I don't have much personal experience with generating graphical source from R data, but my impression has been that [R Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) is the best-established and most-used library for that purpose, and the samples look pretty damn good, so I'd suggest looking there.

Comment: thank you!

but when I type the same thing:

stargazer(attitude,
          type="html",
          out="test.html")


i also get that code, but my HTML-Output is different from yours. I don't habe this three black lines in the table, and the font looks a bit different.

So it definitely must be a problem with my computer...I cannot understand that :)

Comment: It might be browser-related; I'm on the latest Firefox. But it's probably not worth chasing the culprit here, that's not really standard HTML anyway, to code a divider line in a table using a border on an empty row. I suggest looking into [R Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/), rather than pursuing `stargazer`.